# Gson and the argonauts - problem converting javascript array, to json string, to java pojo using gson. Trying to get my structures correct

Tags: java, javascript, json, gson

Here is my json string, that I am acessing in java:

```
json = 
[
    {"id":"123456","Data":"skill2","dmlcrud":false},
    {"id":"123456","Data":"skill3","dmlcrud":true},
    {"id":"123456","Data":"skill14","dmlcrud":true},
    {"id":"123321","Data":"skill1","dmlcrud":false},
    {"id":"123321","Data":"skill14","dmlcrud":false}
]
```

I now want to put it in a collection so ideally/theoretically I would want to do:

```
List<Person> personList = new Gson().fromJson(json, Person.class);
```

and personList.size() would  = 5. I would then loop through personList and preform my relevant actions.

However, my understanding is that I would need to create a container class, which itself contains the person list ? So instead of (public getters/setters removed for brevity, probably syntax errror in there aswell).

```
Class Person {
   private integer id;
   private String Data;
   private Boolean dmlCrud ;
}
```

I would actually need something like ?

```
Class container{
   List<Person> personList;


   static class Person {
      private integer id;
      private String Data;
      private Boolean dmlCrud ;
   }
}
```

However I would then need to alter the javascript json to be somethign different aswell ? Which seems rather problematic as am I creating the json string from a javascript array, using JSON.stringifier.

Any help gratefully received.

**EDIT**

the solution I used was to add

```
public List<Person> personList;
```

to the person class
and alter the json object so that it was

```
{ "personList" :
    [
        {"id":"123456","Data":"skill2","dmlcrud":false},
        {"id":"123456","Data":"skill3","dmlcrud":true},
        {"id":"123456","Data":"skill14","dmlcrud":true},
        {"id":"123321","Data":"skill1","dmlcrud":false},
        {"id":"123321","Data":"skill14","dmlcrud":false}
    ]
}
```

the gson call can then be

```
Person person = new Gson().fromJson(json, Person.class);
```

and the data accessed in a list like so

```
List<Person> personList = person.getPersonList();
```

**EDIT 2**

A second, better, solution is to use this json array

```
[
        {"id":"123456","Data":"skill2","dmlcrud":false},
        {"id":"123456","Data":"skill3","dmlcrud":true},
        {"id":"123456","Data":"skill14","dmlcrud":true},
        {"id":"123321","Data":"skill1","dmlcrud":false},
        {"id":"123321","Data":"skill14","dmlcrud":false}
]
```

and then use

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<SkillsGsonTO>>() {}.getType();
List<Person> personList  = new Gson().fromJson(json,listType);
Person person1 = personList.get(0);
```

where the original class is used

```
Class Person {
       private integer id;
       private String Data;
       private Boolean dmlCrud ;
    }
```

Comment: You're container class could just wrap a java.util.List of Person objects + optionally some other properties without the need to include a static inner class Person.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  OK, I am probably being slow, but what would that look like then ?

Comment: You can take a look at the answer I posted. Basically, I think that you only need a container class if there are other properties you need to store on the list level, for instance you need an additional flag or something. In all other cases, java.util.List and a separate person class will be sufficient.

Comment: So what does the call to gson look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Container class but this only makes sense if you need to ship additional properties on the person list. If this is not the case, you could convert to a java.util.List as well. I think you need to specify the "name" of the list property as a root element in your JSON string. So for instance if you're domain object is a List of Person objects, than your JSON root element is: "persons" or "personList". So you're JSON could look something like:

```
"persons" : {[
     {"id":"123456","Data":"skill2","dmlcrud":false},
     {"id":"123456","Data":"skill3","dmlcrud":true},
     {"id":"123456","Data":"skill14","dmlcrud":true},
     {"id":"123321","Data":"skill1","dmlcrud":false},
     {"id":"123321","Data":"skill14","dmlcrud":false}
]}
```

I could be a little bit off with the syntax, but it should be something similar to this. So to summarize:

In your case you can leave you're Person class untouched and gson should be able to create the List persons for you from the JSON string I suggested.

From the Gson API docs:
If the object that your are deserializing is a ParameterizedType (i.e. contains at least one type parameter and may be an array) then you must use the fromJson(String, Type) method. Here is an example for deserialing a ParameterizedType:

```
 Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();

 Gson gson = new Gson();
 List<String> target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```

So in your case it would be:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Person>>() {}.getType();
List<Person> persons = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
```

where json is your json string obviously

Comment: I don't see how the list would get created. I agree the json object structure needs to change as you suggested. But I must declare a list somewhere in either person or container... ?

Comment: I've editted my answer to be more specific. In your case, you could use Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Person>>() {}.getType(); and get the List<Person> reference with a call to new Gson().fromJson(json, listType), where json is your json string. I hope this clarifies it.

Comment: ah ok, that looks a bit neater than my edit, I will give it a try. Thanks.  What exactly is this  "Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Person>>() {}.getType();"   doing then ?

Comment: It will get the underlying type instance for the generic type see http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.5/docs/javadocs/index.html

Comment: with your suggestion the extra person in json string is not required, it takes the json array. I will update my question

Comment: I never seen this syntax before :  "  {}.getType(); "  can you provide any further explanation of whats going on?

Comment: TypeToken is an abstract class. So basically, you're creating an anonymous class and call the default implementation for getType() on it.